# Minecraft Bukkit Server - Map problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I'm using Bukkit for a personal Minecraft Server. The problem is that the map have something wrong with biomes... see for yourself:

[image: Map stripes and squares from dynmap]
[image: In-game screenshot]

Why these stripes and squares of different biomes?
How do I regenerate the map without this?

**More info**:
CraftBukkit version: **[1.6.2-R1.0-b2879](http://dl.bukkit.org/downloads/craftbukkit/view/02342_1.6.2-R1.0/)**.
 Plugins: **[dynmap](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/dynmap/)**, **[MOTDColor](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/motdcolor/)**.
 This is a multiplayer private server hosted on my machine (playing with friends) and I just created it

Comment: We're going to need a lot more context. Can we get a list of your plugins, your CraftBukkit version, whether this is a one-player private server or mutliplayer private server, whether you have updated CraftBukkit or any plugins recently, how many players have op-level command permission, whether you have WorldEdit installed, and anything else you can think of that could describe your server's situation?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. CraftBukkit version: 1.6.2-R0.1-b2838jnks. Plugins: dynmap, MOTDColor. This is a multiplayer private server hosted on my machine (playing with friends) and I just created it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say, can you please add such information to the question. :)

Comment: Also, can I ask why you're using an old beta build (2838) instead of the latest recommended build (2879)?

Comment: It wasn't available when i created the server :) i try to update now

Comment: Have you confirmed that this striping exists in the world itself, (IE walking/flying there in game,) and not just in dynmap?

Comment: Yes, i can confirm that. Look at the screenshot I just added to the question

Comment: Er, you can't make a new map? Or all maps generated by the server come out like this? Did you try making a map in single-player then transferring it to the server?

Comment: @Oneiros Updating your server *now* won't do anything -- it'll make it harder to diagnose, actually. Once the map's been generated, it'll stay like that throughout versions.

Comment: I just deleted the "world" folder, the server recreated it but it's just the same map as before... wtf?

Comment: @Oneiros What's the seed? I believe the seed is stored outside the "world" folder.

Comment: Where should it be located?

Comment: I just deleted the whole server folder, i always get crappy maps...

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to not create another world, you can delete the chunks using [McEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/) and then start your server back up again. This will reload the chunks again according to the seed of the map.

Answer (score 0):

Create a map by yourself, without using BUKKIT or other kind of servers.

Create a map in single player, "create new world", etc. Then copy your world.save from your .minecraft folder ([...]\Roaming.minecraft\saves) and paste in your server folder, but rename it to what it was firstly (if the "corrupted world" is named "world", rename your new world you made in minecraft to "world" too).

Thats a simple thing you can do to stop doing that.

If the problem continues, the error is in your server, sorry; try to update the server again or update the plugins (or do the both).